# Get nearest values without loop in array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, random, numbers

Given an array :

```
   $foo = Array(
         99=>'Lowest Numbers',
        123=>'Low Numbers',
        456=>'High Numbers',
        777=>'Highest Numbers',
   );
```

... and the value '144',  I would like to return the nearest low value, and nearest high value without having to loop through each element in the array as the actual array is quite large.

The expected result from '144' would be 123=>'Low Numbers'

I currently have the following code :

```
    function name($color,$fuzzy=false) {
        global $resene;
        $long = 0;
        if(is_array($color)) {
            $long = Color::hex2lng(Color::rgb2hex($color));
        } else {
            $long = Color::hex2lng($color);
        }

        if(isset($resene[$long])) {
            echo $resene[$long];
        } else {
            if($fuzzy) {
                $resene[$long] = '';
                ksort($resene);

                // This is where I am having problems
                                    // The array is sorted, so it should be a simple
                                    // matter of getting the previous and next value
                                    // somehow since we know the position we want to
                                    // start at exists because it has been added.

                echo 'No color name found';
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically, the concept is pretty straightforward since we are injecting the value that wasn't found into the array, we know it exists.  Sorting on key, now ensures that the two closest keys are the closest matches to the number being searched for.

The above function is actually a search based on Hex or RGB color that is converted to base 10 ( long value ).

The keys in the array are non-incremental, meaning it isn't 0,1,2,3, and even if i 'flipped' the array, the keys would then be strings, and again, nothing incremental to get the closest.

I was considering a split or something, however that seems to split the array based on how many elements in -- not based on the key.

This is essentially the last step to make this work -- without having to loop through every element.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a Pastbin of the Static function I wrote which returns an Array() of Colors using the Long value of the color as the Key and the Value is the String Name of the color.

[Color Index Array](http://pastebin.com/pkAL9CTy)

Comment: I am not sure this is possible without using some sort of loop, any way you look at it you need to loop through values

Comment: To do it without a loop you'd have to precalculate all the possible results and store in an index that gets updated whenever the array changes. If you already had a separate array with all the numbers from 0 to max (assuming unsigned here), and the array position of the closest answer for each number then you could do a lookup and it's order 1. Otherwise it's order n and you need a loop.

Comment: Maybe read a little about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm and think about using recursion

Comment: anyway have you benchmarked this thing? how big is this array? looping through an array once is usually not a big deal, it's linear. It's when things get O(n^2) and worse that performance really tends to scale poorly. Also what Chitowns said, you can make it O(log n) instead of O(n).

Comment: What is the "nearest" low/high value if the array key actually exists (e.g. `456` in your example) ?

Answer (score 4):

As thelolcat pointed out you probably don't need to worry about performance as much here, but you could try a variation of binary search. There is no way to skip the search here because you can't cut in to ksort(). Here's just a quick draft I came up with:

```
//$resene is your input ksort()-ed array, $long is the key which position and neighbours you're trying to find
$keys = array_keys($resene);
$min = reset($keys);
$s = key($keys);   // = 0
$max = end($keys);
$e = key($keys);   // = count($resene)
do {
    $guess = $s + (int)(($long - $min)/($max - $min)*($e - $s));
    if ($keys[$guess] > $long) {
        $e = $guess - 1;
        $max = $keys[$e];
        $min = $keys[++$s];
    } elseif ($keys[$guess] < $long) {
        $s = $guess + 1;
        $min = $keys[$s];
        $max = $keys[--$e];
    }
} while ($keys[$guess] != $long && $e != $s);
echo 'Me = '.$keys[$guess].'; prev = '.$keys[$guess - 1].'; next = '.$keys[$guess + 1];
```

I ran a few tests, on an array of 20,000 random numbers from 0 to 5,000,000, with a random target value of that array, I'm getting a hit in 3-4 loops. Of course don't forget to check if prev/next exist.

Also it would work better if you could use a normal indexed array and use normal sort() on it to avoid duping the array with array_keys(). I guess you tried to use keys here just to gain some speed and you don't have anything useful in array values? If so, you should switch to indexed array.

You could get it work even better if you refrain from using k/sort() and use something like this to find the position to insert new value in the first place. You could then use array_splice() to insert it and you would already know its position an hence, prev/next.

**UPDATE**

After looking at Method 2 in your example, it became more clear what you were trying to do. I was curious how much of an index I could come up with in PHP, so here is a function, that gives same results as yours:

```
function fast_nearest($array, $value, $exact=false) {
    if (isset($array[$value])) {
        // If exact match found, and searching for exact (not nearest), return result.
        return array($value => $array[$value], 'exact' => true);
    } elseif ($exact || empty($array)) {
        return false;
    }
    // else
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $min = $keys[0];
    $s = 0;
    $max = end($keys);
    $e = key($keys);
    if ($s == $e) {
        // only one element, it's closest
        return array_merge($array, array('exact' => false));
    } elseif ($value < $min) {
        return array($min => $array[$min], 'exact' => false);
    } elseif ($value > $max) {
        return array($max => $array[$max], 'exact' => false);
    }
    $result = false;
    do {
        $guess = $s + (int)(($value - $min) / ($max - $min) * ($e - $s));
        if ($guess < $s) {
            // oops, off the scale; we found it
            $result = $keys[$s];
        } elseif ($guess > $e) {
            $result = $keys[$e];
        } elseif ($keys[$guess] > $value && $keys[$guess - 1] < $value) {
            // found range
            $result = (($value - $keys[$guess - 1]) < ($keys[$guess] - $value)
                ? $keys[$guess - 1]
                : $keys[$guess]);
        } elseif ($keys[$guess] < $value && $keys[$guess + 1] > $value) {
            $result = (($value - $keys[$guess]) < ($keys[$guess + 1] - $value)
                ? $keys[$guess]
                : $keys[$guess + 1]);
        } elseif ($keys[$guess] > $value) {
            // narrowing search area
            $e = $guess - 1;
            $max = $keys[$e];
        } elseif ($keys[$guess] < $value) {
            $s = $guess + 1;
            $min = $keys[$s];
        }
    } while ($e != $s && $result === false);
    if ($result === false) {
        throw new Exception("Math laws don't work in this universe.");
    }
    return array($result => $array[$result], 'exact' => false);
}
```

I compiled most of exit scenarios scattered in your function at the top, and also I dropped inserting an item into array since it doesn't persist outside the function. You could easily add it with `array_splice()` at found position.

I ran speed tests on both functions (yours and mine) to compare on arrays of random numbers from 1 to 1,000,000,000 (yes, both functions were fed with same inputs):

- 20,000 items:

  - `fast_nearest()` - **7.3 ms** average on 1,000 runs
  - `nearest()` - **207 ms** average on same 1,000 runs
- 200,000 items:

  - `fast_nearest()` - **70 ms** average on 10 runs (sorry, 1,000 was too long of a wait for this size)
  - `nearest()` - **2,798 ms** average on 10 runs
- 2,000,000 items:

  - `fast_nearest()` - **937 ms** average on 2 runs
  - `nearest()` - **22,156 ms** average on 2 runs

Obviously, both don't work very well on huge arrays, so if you have to manipulate that much of data - I'd suggest using something like database server with proper indexing, PHP isn't the right tool for it.

Comment: @Dan Well, you wouldn't need your own loop if you use array_search()... But that doesn't mean the loop isn't there, it would just be performed internally by array_search(). As everyone told you already, you can't do it without any kind of loop.

Comment: @Dan, I've added a "closest match" solution as you requested, it wasn't very clear from your initial question. Also, I did your job only for one reason - I made a bet with a colleague that I could make it find closest match in 1,000,000 items in under 1 second on my local environment (AMD Athlon 2.71 GHz). And it works marvels without `array_keys()` step, if indexed array of ordered numbers is provided from outside.

Comment: @Dan, you could get wrong result only if you forgot `ksort()` from your initial question. I assumed that was arbitrary condition. That would also affect speed. Anyway, what you have on pastebin is by no means large array, you should do just fine with straightforward `$min=null; $res=null; foreach ($colors as $long => $name) { if (abs($value-$long) < $min || $min === null) { $min = abs($value-$long); $res = $long; } return //$res...` without losing time on ksort really.

Comment: @Dan I see. Well, don't worry then, it'll pass. :) Reality is, that sometimes PHP's internal solutions are times worse than what you could code yourself even being at disadvantage of having your code interpreted. Furthermore, you could look at things like KPHP or HipHop.

Comment: Of course that using a loop will be faster than ksorting + searching array (which also loops btw). OP here is delusional. This question is very unproductive, someone should just delete it!

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
$input = 142;
$offset = 0;

while(true){
  if(isset($foo[$input - $offset])){
    $found = array($input - $offset => $foo[$input - $offset]);
    break;
  }  

  if(isset($foo[$input + $offset])){
    $found = array($input - $offset => $foo[$input + $offset]);
    break;
  }      

  $offset++;
}
```

It should be a little cheaper than a standard loop

How big is that array anyway? Why is speed important?

**Edit:**

NVM. Your question is wrong. I just did a timing test on `ksort()` on a associative array of 100K elements. It takes 0.07 seconds. While a FULL foreach loop, takes 0.01 seconds!

Comment: No you dont need ksort if you're doing a full loop because you store the distance in a variable and continue to update it when it gets smaller